# Adding fieldset and legend to group multiple radio button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this error:

> Success Criteria 1.3.1 Info and Relationships (A)
>
> Check 168: Form missing fieldset and legend to group multiple radio
> buttons.
>
> Repair: Add a fieldset and legend element to the form for
> each group of radio buttons.

How do I adjust this to clear this error?

Where am I supposed to add the fieldset and legend?

```
<div id="content" class="container content">

<div class="headline">
  <h2>Transaction Type</h2>
</div>

<p><strong>Types Of Mail Packets:</strong> There are four types of mail packets that are based on the type of transaction.</p>

<form name="titleTypes" id="titleTypes" method="post" action="process.cfm">

<div>
  <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
  <label for="rgroup" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Motor-Vehicle-Or-Travel-Trailer-Title">
            <input id="Motor-Vehicle-Or-Travel-Trailer-Title" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MV/titleTypeMV.cfm" />
            Motor Vehicle / Travel Trailer Title</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Mobile-Home">
            <input id="Mobile-Home" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MH/mobileHome.cfm" />
            Mobile Home</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Vessel">
            <input id="Vessel" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="BOAT/boat.cfm" />
            Vessel</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Duplicate-Or-Replacement-Title">
            <input id="Duplicate-Or-Replacement-Title" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="DUPL/duplicate.cfm" />
            Duplicate / Replacement Title</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn"><i></i>Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that error from an HTML validator?

Comment: Yes from a web accessibility checker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears OP layout is using Bootstrap so the best tag to change into a [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) is the [`.form-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/), the `<legend>` is always the first child of the `<fieldset>`. The following demo wraps all `<input type="radios">` and `<button>` into one `<fieldset>`.

Some additional changes to tags, classes, position, etc. were made to make the layout a little more semantical and there are [Bootstrap custom classes](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) that enhance radio button appearance as well. Note: among the changes, the first radio button has the [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) which applies to all tags with the `[name="rgroup"]`. Should the user attempt to submit the form without selecting a radio button, an error occurs and sending data is interrupted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>DMV Titles</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main id="content" class="container content">

    <header class="headline">
      <h1>Transaction Type</h1>
    </header>

    <p class='lead'><small><strong>Types Of Mail Packets:</strong> There are four types of mail packets that are based on the type of transaction.</small></p>

    <form id="titleTypes" name="titleTypes" action="process.cfm" method="post">

      <header>
        <output for="rgroup" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</output>
      </header>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Title Types</legend>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="motor" name="rgroup" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="MV/titleTypeMV.cfm" required>
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="motor">Motor Vehicle / Travel Trailer</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="mobile" name="rgroup" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="MH/mobileHome.cfm">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="mobile">Mobile Home</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="boat" name="rgroup" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="BOAT/boat.cfm">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="boat">Mobile Home</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="dupe" name="rgroup" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="DUPL/duplicate.cfm">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="dupe">Duplicate / Replacement Title</label>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit"><i></i>Next</button>
          </fieldset>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```